# Creating client to web service takes a dozen seconds - Xamarin Forms PCL

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a following problem: creation client to web service takes too long. I have web service SOAP which I import to Xamarin Forms PCL as service reference. I create client in static class and with Tasks and Asyncs methods. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MyApp.WebService;

public static class Client
{
    public static ServiceClient Connection;

    private const string UserName = "admin";
    private const string Password = "password";
    private static string _username;
    private static string _password;
    private static string _serviceAddress;

    private static void Login()
    {
        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding
        {
            SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10000),
            Security =
            {
                Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly,
                Transport = {ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic}
            },
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1024 * 10,
            AllowCookies = true
        };

        Connection = new ServiceClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(_serviceAddress)); // takes around 12 seconds, i don't know what's going so long
        Connection.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = UserName;
        Connection.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = Password;
        Connection.OpenAsync();
        Connection.UserAuthorisationCompleted += UserAuthorisationCompleted;
        Connection.UserAuthorisationAsync(_username, _password);
    }

    private static void UserAuthorisationCompleted(object sender, UserAuthorisationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // here I checking result - at the moment it's doesn't matter
    }

    public static Task LoginAsync(string username, string password, string serviceAddress)
    {
        _username = username;
        _password = password;
        _serviceAddress = serviceAddress;

        var task = new Task(Login);
        task.Start();
        return task;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why it takes so long? On the server nothing is at this point.

Comment: You set timeout to 10 seconds. If there is nothing on server it might wait 10 seconds before returns an error

Comment: Client sends request after round 12 seconds of doing nothing.

Comment: I am using SOAP for years and don't have any problems

Comment: In Xamarin Forms? Could you paste here your client connection/user authorisation code?

Comment: It is auto-generated code in PCL Profile 78

Comment: How to generate the code? Sorry, but I don't know what's going on.

Comment: add service reference to pcl

Comment: Yes, because you have to write some code to initialize connection from your app, I'm right?

Comment: the code will depend on the service you have. Mine is:                 CPService3Client cpServiceClient = new CPService3Client(_webServiceBinding, new EndpointAddress(CpService3Uri));   cpServiceClient.WsCPGetApiVersionsCompleted += (s, e) =>{code};  cpServiceClient.WsCPGetApiVersionsAsync();

Comment: You can read more here https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/

Comment: So we have similar codes but my sends request to server after round 10 seconds... :( and I don't know why

Comment: from the code I see it looks like you are using rest service with basic authentication. That doesn't look like SOAP consumption client. If you expose your service without security I can generate a client and then you can add authenitation

Comment: Thanks for your help but at this moment I can't do this because this service isn't my. I maybe try change te binding yet...

Comment: I don't know how to edit comment but I forgot add that this service is SOAP service, not REST.